# AWSSDK.S3 "Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period"

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, aws-sdk-net

I want to load an audio file via the `PutObjectAsync()` method but after a while this exception is thrown:

`ex = {"Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period."}`

For a .txt file this method works very well but once I load a file other than .txt the exception is thrown.

- size of my txt file: 2MB (works)
- size of my mp3 file: 700Ko (does not work)

My code:

```cs
using(var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  await request.File.CopyToAsync(inputStream);
  var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(){
    BucketName = "<my_bucket_name>",
    Key = "<file_key>",
    InputStream = inputStream,
  };
  await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest);
}
```

I am using:

- .NET 6
- AWSSDK.S3: Version="3.7.9.42"

can someone help me please?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this OP? I am having the exact same issue and it is driving me nuts !

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while trying to connect to OVHCloud via the AWSSDK S3 API. After a lot of trial and error, I found that chunking doesn't work, and you also need to explicitly set the http status (UseHttp - note that false means https).

I hope this saves someone else the countless hours it cost me.

```
_s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = ServiceURL,
    AuthenticationRegion = Region,
    UseHttp = false
});



var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    UseChunkEncoding = false,
    BucketName = BucketName,
    Key = key,
    InputStream = fileStream
};

await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest);
```